# save a webpage with urllib

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib

```
import urllib
url='www.something.com/something..'
f = urllib.urlretrieve(url,'copy.html')
```

this code only creates a html file which provides direct link to the url specified (ie, it is not accessible offline). How to to store the webpage so that it will be available offline.??

Answer (score 2):

You need to get all the other resources the page is pointing to (CSS files, images ...).

I suggest that you use "wget", it already does what you want.